# JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager

Tags: queue, jms, websphere

I am trying to listen to a IBM queue for which I have the queue details. I am trying to make a connection to the queue manager but get the below error :

> ERROR = JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QTDC1GC2' with
> connection mode 'Bindings' and host name
> 'gbahevl616.ics.express.tnt(1432)'.

Answer (score 0):

Bindings mode connects to the queue manager on the same logical machine using Java Native Interface. If you need to connect over TCP/IP over a network, you should configure your connection to be Client mode. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031720_.htm How you do that will depend on whether your connection is provided by an application server like WebSphere Application Server or if you are making the connection directly in code.